# questions about basic supply and demand curve theory

Tags: mathematical-economics, supply-and-demand, theory

I've been getting into mathematics for its own sake and finding the same type of math can be applied across various fields and diverse domains (physics, engineering, data science, ecology, economics, etc). Some of the questions from the calc book I'm reading have economics questions so I decided to upgrade my economic understanding and explore the field. I discovered about Paul Samuelson's book Foundations of Economic Analysis, but I only just started. Maybe my questions will be answered there but I've been reading wikipedia as well as recalling teachings from my old college econ classes.

1. Regarding the demand curve, can this ever be calculated with precision for a given period, or even in general? What I mean is how would they gather from all the raw data out there what the shape of the curve would be? If the price has reached relative equilibrium at say $15/unit, how would they know what the shape would be at 20 or 30 or 10 if it never even approaches those ranges? (I'm ignoring the fact that by the time the curve is calculated, it may be outdated). It seems like producing a curve is more complicated in the real world than is suggested by texts and teachers and articles, so is it basically just an idealized approximation and a didactic tool, or is such a real curve used in the real world? If we can make such useful curves, is it done with great statistical software and linear algebra? We receive curves and equations as given in textbooks and I never thought critically about how those were arrived at. Maybe the curve can be calculated in a narrow range- the range of price fluxes that are realistic and meaningful- maybe instead of zero to 100 dollars for an item, it's 32-59 as the range may never exceed. Maybe this is one solution - to zoom in, and then take snapshots in time to approximate an underlying curve in terms of the real value of a currency.
2. On the supply side, the supply curve suggests that a manufacturer or a firm or the market as a whole will supply a certain quantity of goods when it can receive a certain price for said good. This makes a lot of sense superficially- the linear relationship would be the higher the price, the more profit, the more to sell. However, this too, when I think deep about it, kind of falls apart. At the very least it assumes some kind of constraint. In reality I think that if a firm can make 1 dollar profit on something it sells for $5 while producing 10M, it would actually want to produce an infinite amount. As long as it makes any profit, it would want to produced an infinite amount, unless there is some constraint, such as an oversupply will reduce or left shift the demand curve which will lower the price input of the supply curve, which is basically like two correlated functions or relationships. I'm not sure the mathematical word for it- recursive relationships or interdependent relationships, where the output of one function is an input to another- but they don't teach this in the classes I was in. Barring these constraints, a producer would produce and sell an infinite supply if they were a rational economic actor, if they made even just a little bit of profit per unit, and similarity they would produce zero of a unit if they lost money on the deal, not considering fixed cost and interest payment coverages. In other words a rational firm would be all or nothing. The two curves must be correlated functionally. The oversupply of goods in the real world (flooding the market) depresses prices, but this is never talked about in simplifications.

   Continuing the question above, there'd have to be some constraint to production to limit what they produce, otherwise they'd produce an infinite amount. It could be the number of workers, or the supply of raw material. A rational economic actor would produce only one item- that of the most profit, notwithstanding company divisions, different subdivisions and desire for product diversity. They would ideally put all their free capital in what gives the most bang for the buck, all else equal. There is a natural constraint baked into the demand curve- that is an individual or nation's income (and access to credit). Also there are natural constraints- most people only need 1 refrigerator, maybe 2, and a multifamily building only needs one per unit, so we won't see many more refrigerators owned than there are independent households. None of these are constraints for the supply curve - income wise because because the supply curve is the source of income- the sale of goods, constraint wise because it can produce as many as it can produce- it can grow its factory in theory. The only constraints are production constraints and cost constraints, which may vary with usage. I don't mean variable costs- I mean the cost of a commodity like tin for bronze might vary as the consumption of it goes up. Besides these constraints, they could and should 'go infinite' in their production if there is profit to be made, to borrow the term of a popular book right now. Many textbook problems I recall deal with this by constraining what can be produced- raw materials x, y, z, which can be assigned to various products, but this is not encoded in the supply curve itself. It elides or neglects this aspect, so does it implicitly refer to or presuppose a scale, a scope, like Newtonian gravity, outside of which it falls apart?
3. I was thinking of what moves the demand curve. Consumer tastes, marketing, human need etc all make sense, but I was thinking of salesmen, a sales force. If a guy goes out and sells something and gets a commission, the manifest demand a posteriori has increased by human action. If a company builds a sales force, are they moving the demand curve as opposed to just moving inventory? Then can a company or marketing association can toggle and modify its own demand curve? With other things like marketing, this seems to play on human tastes in the abstract, but with a sales team, it seems more direct and not have to do with abstract 'demand', but the effect is the same. Because it is direct action, it doesn't seem to me like it should be considered a change in demand curve. It seems like its breaking the rules to some extent, and breaking economic theory, but then how would we account for what's happening, i.e. the numbers? This question is not as fundamental to the system. It might be just a curiosity but a curiosity nonetheless, where humans become agents in their economies.

   If human action and self interest drives the forces that produce equilibrium, new technologies, created by entrepreneurs, might be disruptors- until new equilibrium is created. These disruptions, these new technologies, are not foreseen by economics, are not part of economics itself or economics proper- unless there is a more abstract expression of economics, like abstract algebra to math- factoring in distruptors- political, technological or otherwise. Economics and its central equilibrium concept, cannot predict what will be. Disruptions are external events it seems to me, that happen, and that economies absorb and integrate, from which equilibrium occurs through self interest and the various "laws", but humans can do pushing from within and from without the system, both in terms of sales from within and invention from without. Perhaps as I said invention and even political social change can be accounted for in a more abstract socio-politico-economic-historic theory (that sounds like what Marx tried to do actually, in his way, with his biases) but then we're starting to get into a theory of everything. Humans, whether or not we have free will, are actors nonetheless- not just consumers and producers but actors generally, inventors, protestors, rioters and destructors of property, builders of property and visionaries, investors, defenders. It seems like we can change the system from without (invention, political economy) and we can toggle it within- sales, marketing, taxing and lobbying for taxes. (Big established companies may benefit from taxing their type of product, apparently, as a way to disproportionately disadvantage smaller firms in their market).

I think that sums up my questions for now. I'm a polymath kind of guy. I'm trying to figure out what to do with this thing called economics and what kind of footing it is on. I know we need economics, in our political sphere, in our family lives and as investors, workers, consumers, producers and businessmen. I know we need knowledge of markets and access to data on a range of topics like credit, housing, interest, etc to inform our decisions so I'm trying to establish sound footing and foundations of the basic concepts of supply and demand- not so much the concepts but the use of graphs and maths for computational specifics. I know it's a relatively new field, less than 150 years since Principles was published by Marshall. I know Samuelson respected Marshall as an economist but thought he could have been better and had some critiques but I'm still too fresh to understand them.

I've only started Samuelson's book so maybe he'll have answers but I now wonder if what I've been taught up to now about supply and demand curves have just been a convenient fiction at best and how mathematical you can really make economics, and how to do said math, and why so many texts and such present at as simple and straightforward.

"The more one knows, the more one knows one doesn't know"

"but knowing math is helpful to knowing in general"

Comment: Can you please let me know more specifically your background so I can tailor my answer to your areas, given you've taken the time to carefully construct your question?  Do you have a pure math degree and which courses did you complete?  Do you have familiarity with statistics and probabilities?  What about financial math, particularly call options, put options, butterflies, etc. the math of stock derivatives?